# Calculating file offset after a write

Tags: c, linux, file, offset

I am writing a program where I log all writes to a file and just before process termination I write all writes in place i.e from log to actual file. Now, in the log each record of type something like :

```
 offset, length, data
```

After a write I need to calculate the offset so that I can lseek to that position when i finally write in the actual file so as to write the next write or for read.

Will current offset position+bytes written give me the file offset after a write.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [fgetpos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetpos) to get the file offset and [fsetpos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fsetpos) to set the file offset.

Comment: @David..I need to calculate the file offset after a read or write

Comment: ftell/fgetpos do that: tell you the "file position indicator"... the offset relative to the beginning; otherwise, the offset from the prev position is just the number of data written/read... — so the answer to your last line is "yes".

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve that:

1. **First Way** (In this case position will be updated automatically to how much you have read.)

   1. Read all log content into memory
   2. Sort them by (offset + length) growth
   3. Using consecutive read calls
2. **Second Way** (most portable)

   1. Using **fgetpos(), fgetpos64()** and **fsetpos(),fsetpos64()** set of functions.
3. **Third Way**

   1. Using **ftello(), fseeko()** and **ftello64(), fseeko64()** set of functions.
4. **Fourth Way** (less portable)

   1. Using **ftell(), fseek()** and **ftell64(), fseek64()** set of functions.

The difference between **func()** and **func64()** is that func64() uses correct 64-bit offset which eliminates problem with files more than 4Gb, while func() uses *int* type which could be 32 or 64 bits, depending on the architecture.

The **fseeko()** and **ftello()** functions are identical to **fseek()** and **ftell()** except that the *offset* argument of fseeko() and the return value of ftello() is of type *off*_t instead of *long*.

As a conclusion the best practice is to use fgetpos64()/fsetpos64() or ftello64()/fseeko64().
As much as possible try to avoid any using of ftell() and fseek().